# DELETE then INSERT is randomly raising a duplicate key violates unique constraint error

Tags: postgresql

I have a query (for a website) that replaces old data with new data.

I run the query in one call to the database via the PHP `pg_query` function and also use pgbouncer with `transaction` pool mode. I would be very surprised if two of the same queries are running at the same time, but is that the only explanation for this? I don't have any triggers or SERIAL columns on the table.

```
CREATE TABLE mydata (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    val TEXT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE mydata ADD CONSTRAINT mydata_unique (id);
```

The statement that raises the conflict is

```
DELETE FROM mydata WHERE id IN (1,2,3); 
INSERT INTO mydata (id,val) VALUES (1,'one'); 
INSERT INTO mydata (id,val) VALUES (2,'two'); 
INSERT INTO mydata (id,val) VALUES (3,'three');
```

Version PostgreSQL 12.2

Comment: Perhaps you can try with UPSERT (https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: why three INSERT statements not one?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? `select version();` will tell you.

Comment: @IVOGELOV Upsert would resolve this but im interested to know why it is happening in the first case if im deleting and inserting in the same statement.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Just the way the application prepares the query

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are not running these statements in parallel, but one after the other.

Still, this could easily cause conflicts if several database sessions are doing the same thing at the same time: a second session may insert rows after the first session deleted the old rows, but before it inserted the new rows.

To protect yourself from that with row locks, run all statements in a single transaction. This may occasionally lead to a deadlock, which is no big deal - just repeat the transaction that failed.

Comment: You may also set a short timeout, e.g. `SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '1s';` after you `BEGIN` the transaction.

Comment: @IVOGELOV How would that help, if you don't use a single transaction? There will not be any locks held for a longer time.

Comment: I think it will help in the case of a deadlock by shortening its timeout - but I could be wrong.

Comment: No, deadlocks will be checked after 1 second anyway. Besides, I see no deadlock in the question.